# RecyclerView is not returning all items

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm making my first java android app and I'm having some issues with the RecyclerView.

I have a RecyclerView with a custom layout for each element.

I want to make that when I press the toolbar button, the Image Buttons inside EACH layout element inside the RecyclerView turn visible or invisible

This is the toolbar edit button code:

```
            ArrayList<View> dest=new ArrayList<View>();
            recView= findViewById(R.id.newListView);
            recView.setItemViewCacheSize(0);
            recView.findViewsWithText(dest,getString(R.string.onesingleuserlayout),View.FIND_VIEWS_WITH_CONTENT_DESCRIPTION);

            for (View oneUserLayout:dest)
            {
                oneUserLayout.findViewById(R.id.btnDelete).setVisibility(newVisibility);
                oneUserLayout.findViewById(R.id.btnEdit).setVisibility(newVisibility);
            }
```

It hides almost all the elements, but not every one of them. The ones shown behave correctly,  and SOMETIMES the ones not showing don't.

[image: Screenshot]

I think that it is related to the cached items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change your approach and instead of calling all those findView methods from outside the RecyclerView, implement a method on the adapter to change a boolean variable representing the visibility of the buttons and then call notifyDataSetChanged to force the layout manager to redraw all the visible itens and since all items reference the boolean variable, when new items are redrawn they will have the new visibility.

Comment: I'm on the cellphone now and it is dificult for me to insert example code now. Please say to me if my explanation is more or less clear!

Comment: This works like a charm. The only downside is that when the buttons turn visible, the layout doesn't animate automatically with "animateLayoutChanges" because it redraws everything. Still i think this is the way

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line, in order to permit caching:

```
recView.setItemViewCacheSize(0);
```

[Here](https://blog.mindorks.com/how-does-recyclerview-work-internally) it's explained how it works (which may also explain, why caching is required).

Comment: I added that line because it wasn't working before. By default is 2 and the problem occurs with 3 elements, now when it is set to 0, it only occurs with 1. Still, the link you shared is pretty interesting.

Comment: That link also explains the issue ... there is a reason why it is being called `RecyclerView`. According to the GIF you'd added, the items to be manipulated are not being selected properly... because you only catch the ones within the visible view-port, but not those below the fold - simply because they aren't attached yet, while they're still below the fold.

Comment: And how can I access to those Views? I'm using findViewsWithText. Or do I have to get the Views using their index?

Comment: I'd suggest to switch or manipulate the layout of the `CardView`... because accessing these from the outside with a method that only catches the visible views is rather useless. Please consider accepting my answer, in case this helps.